# Problem with opening a view, Error 404, Not Found

Tags: php, html, laravel

So... The Error might be obvious but I cant find it. Im using Laravel 9.
The Error is '404 Not found'.

This is the Route

```
Route::get('/list', [ValidationController::class, 'index']);
```

This is the function inside the controller.(It is the correct Controller)

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data = Validation::all();
        return view('products.list', compact('data'));
    }
```

And this is the HTML to call this route

```
<div>
    <a href="/list">Products</a>
</div>
```

The File 'list' exists in the 'products' directory.

Thank you for your answers.. :)

My show function in a different Controller works just fine..

```
public function show(Product $product)
    {
        return view('products.show', compact('product'));
    }
```

Comment: The Name is: list.blade.php

Comment: It still doesnt work :(

Comment: Configuration cache cleared successfully.
Configuration cached successfully. still doesnt open the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path in your `href` attribute is most likely the issue. When creating a link, Laravel has a helper function to help out with routes: [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route). The best practise is to name your route in your `routes.php` file:

```php
Route::get('/list', [ValidationController::class, 'index'])->name('route.name');
```

When creating a link, you will be able to just do this:

```php
<a href="{{ route('route.name') }}">Products</a>
```